# Why is the SSH key not accessible?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have 2 remote servers, and I need to transfer files from one server to another.

In serverA I created an SSH key (id_rsa) using the sudo user, and copied the public key into serverB (into authorized_keys file of the same sudo user).

Hosts file

```
[servers]
prod_server ansible_host=IP_prod
new_server ansible_host=IP_new

[servers:vars]
ansible_user=sudo_user
ansible_sudo_pass=sudo_password
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/sudo_user_key
```

Play

```
- name: Transfer files from prod to new server
  hosts: new_server
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - rsync
```

Task

```
- name: Copy files to new server
  synchronize:
    src: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
    dest: /opt
  delegate_to: prod_server
```

When running the playbook an error shows up:

```
Identity file /home/sudo_user/.ssh/sudo_user_key not accessible: No such file or directory. Permission denied (publickey).
```

The task should look up for the `/home/sudo_user/.ssh/id_rsa` key instead of `sudo_user_key` one...

How should I handle this?

Comment: You have configured the key location with `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/sudo_user_key`.  If that is not the right key, it should be changed to the right one.

Comment: You're right, but even if I set the right key ```id_rsa``` another error shows up:
```change_dir \"/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld\" failed: Permission denied```
It means that the ```sudo_user``` don't have root privileges to access that file...

Comment: If I set ```become: true``` it would be possible to access the ```fullchain.pem``` file, but the play will try then to transfer the file using the root user, and the SSH key ```id_rsa``` is owned by the ```sudo_user```...